# How to configure VS Code to automatically close deleted files when switching branches?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way in VS Code to have it automatically close deleted file tabs when switching branches? I tend to switch branches in [Tower](https://www.git-tower.com/mac) and when I go back to VS Code a bunch of deleted files still show as open tabs. This causes confusion when I do a rename across the project since it readds the file back to the project at that point.

Is there a way to fix this to have it close deleted file tabs when switching branches?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you want to enable:

```
"workbench.editor.closeOnFileDelete": true,  // default is false
```

> Controls whether editors showing a file that was opened during the
>   session should close automatically when getting deleted or renamed by
>   some other process. Disabling this will keep the editor open  on such
>   an event. Note that deleting from within the application will always
>   close the editor and that dirty files will never close to preserve
>   your data.

The files would be deleted immediately in vscode when deleted in another application - if that is what you want, not only when you switch branches.